# Font face quality issue in firefox (windows os)

Tags: css, rendering, font-face

I have a site where the font face usually works, even in ie.
But in firefox letters are jagged and ugly, I think a rendering problem. In firefox the MAC functions normally, as in other browsers. I tried to solve a lot of ways without success.
Can anyone help me?

---

[link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvJGY.jpg)

```css
@font-face {
font-family: 'Myriad Pro';
src: url('myriadpro-regular.eot');
src: url('myriadpro-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('myriadpro-regular.woff') format('woff'),
     url('myriadpro-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),        
     url('myriadpro-regular.svg#myriadpro-regular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bother you but as far as i know you can't use Adobes font in websites, well technicaly you can't use them on anything, that will allow other people to access the font (i could for example use you Myriad Pro font just by fooling around firebug).

As far as your project is hiting live, anyways hope my info helps.